# Getting BLOB data in Android, null exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite, null, blob

I insert a Bitmap data (transed byte[] array) in Sqlite where BLOB column.
I use this source to get the data.

```
//Get the data
byte[] byteArray = helper.getPicture(appWidgetId);
//Change byte[] data to Bitmap
Bitmap bmPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

But the android showing up error message, it's bitmap is null
So I added check source.

```
//Get the data
byte[] byteArray = helper.getPicture(appWidgetId);
//Check, If byte is not null
if (byteArray != null) {
//Change it to Bitmap
    Bitmap bmPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
}
```

It's perfect...
I can't understand why added 'if source' can load data.
Why not added 'if source' can not load data.

Its looks like Interface... :<

Comment: Is your helper.getPicture(appWidgetId); an asynchronize call? if not, if statement should make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to debug your application. Set some breakpoints on the right places and go on. It's the easiest way to figure out the values of your variables at the runtime. I assume that there's something wrong with:

```
byte[] byteArray = helper.getPicture(appWidgetId);
```

This method obviously doesn't act as expected sometimes, so go deeper into this one.

The `if` statement doesn't make the wrong behavior disappear, it's only showing you success if the `getPicture` method returns a valid result. So in the case of a null result you just see nothing, right?

Another advice use exceptions to figure out when something went wrong, so you can react on unexpected behavior ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add some logging and check if/when the case that you prevent with your `if` happens.

```
if (byteArray != null) {
    //Change it to Bitmap
    Bitmap bmPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    Log.d("TAG", "it worked :)");
} else {
    Log.d("TAG", "it's null :(");
}
```